# Creating queries using between for year, month and day in separate fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, between

I own a table with year, month and day in separate fields in Postgresql, but I need to make a query using 'between'  these fields. I've tried some crazy things but nothing worked ... Does anyone know help me?

Ex table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  day integer NOT NULL,
  month integer NOT NULL,
  year integer NOT NULL,
)
```

Comment: What do you need?  Date between something?  What have you tried?

Comment: http://bit.ly/15Dyg5d

Comment: My opinion is that you don't.  You create a new field that contains real dates, and you process that field instead.  This structure, for example, allows a 31st day in February, which can seriously damage your data.  Why would this structure be *required*?

Comment: This is a problem, but that database already existed when I joined the company and can not change

Answer (score 8):

Cheat.  You aren't validating these "dates", you are just sorting them.  Validation is a separate task, and the only sane solution is a schema change.

```
CREATE INDEX my_table__date__idx ON test1 (year * 10000 + month * 100 + day);

SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE year * 10000 + month * 100 + day BETWEEN 20130101 AND 20131231;
```

If you don't want huge gaps, use `year*12*31 + month*31 + day`

Comment: +1 : best lateral thinking idea yet :)  I'd also then add a BETWEEN constraint to each field to prevent day = 2013 or day = -13 and month = 55378008, to ensure that this always works...

Comment: +1 That's clever, if the `BETWEEN` dates are proper dates you can just turn them into Integers.

Answer (score 7):

#### Assistance for the dark side

While stuck with your design, this should be **simpler and faster** than any of the solutions proposed so far: *ad-hoc row types*:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  (year, month, day) BETWEEN (2013,7,3)
                          AND     (2013,7,5);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=91eb6776fe073814056a9d05f231b14b)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/83d69/1)</sub>

#### Proper solution

But, really, you should use a **proper table design** to begin with. Save the date as [**`date`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), not as three `integer` columns. That enforces valid dates, as collateral benefit.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  tbl_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
, thedate date NOT NULL
);
```

`thedate` includes all three columns: `day`, `month`, `year` and needs 4 bytes like an `integer`.

Then the task is trivial:
To get day, month, year - or any sub-unit in any form, use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE), [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT), or [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT). These functions are very fast and versatile.

You could create a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) that looks *exactly* like the table you have now:

```sql
CREATE view old_table AS
SELECT tbl_id
     , EXTRACT(day   FROM thedate)::int AS day
     , EXTRACT(month FROM thedate)::int AS month
     , EXTRACT(year  FROM thedate)::int AS year
FROM   my_table;
```

Would still be at least as fast as your table because the source is smaller.

Comment: That's clever, fun to see the little tricks from other RDBMS.

Comment: @GoatCO: Actually, that's **standard SQL**. Ordering by row values or composite types has been in the SQL standard since at least SQL-92.

Comment: Since everyone picks and chooses which standards to implement the `standard` doesn't mean all that much.  This ad-hoc row type is a bit that SQL Server doesn't seem to support.

Comment: Can anyone pls guide me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081188/date-separate-into-year-month-and-day-how-to-check-if-date-exists-into-db?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the table structure to use proper dates, you can make dates from the fields for comparison, something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE to_date(Year||' '||Day||' '||Month, 'YYYY DD MM') BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

If they're all Integers you'll have to convert each to string, I believe `::VARCHAR()` works, or `CAST()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE to_date(Year::varchar(4)||' '||Day::varchar(2)||' '||Month::varchar(2), 'YYYY DD MM') BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Comment: Care to tell me what happens when day = 1 and month = 1?

Comment: `to_date('201311', 'YYYYDDMM')` is not January 1st 2013.

Comment: Hmm..  `SELECT to_date('2009'||'1'||'1', 'YYYY DD MM')` is Jan 1, 2009

Comment: `RIGHT('0000'||Year,4)||RIGHT('00'||Day,2)||RIGHT('00'||Month,2)`?

Comment: okay, what is `SELECT to_date('2009'||'11'||'1', 'YYYYDDMM')` or `SELECT to_date('2009'||'1'||'11', 'YYYYDDMM')`?

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE
  (
       ((day >= :first_day) AND (month  = :first_month) AND (year  = :first_year))
    OR (                        (month >  :first_month) AND (year  = :first_year))
    OR (                                                    (year >  :first_year))
  )
  AND
  (
       ((day <= :final_day) AND (month  = :final_month) AND (year  = :final_year))
    OR (                        (month <  :final_month) AND (year  = :final_year))
    OR (                                                    (year <  :final_year))
  )
```

Which is ***really*** going to destroy any chance of an index seek.  You will likely scan the whole table every time.

You're a million times better off looking to use a real date field.

I would never want to release the above code, never mind have a peer review it.  I'd be mortified.